# IntelliJ gradle dependencies not showing up in external libraries tab

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

So I have switched from eclipse to intelliJ just today and now I'm trying to figure out how to add dependencies with gradle in intelliJ. I made a new gradle project, created a hello world main class and added a single dependency in the build.gradle. I then ran the gradlew build command and clicked the reload all gralde projects button in the gradle tab. It was also showing my dependency in the gradle -> dependencies tab. It is however not showing up under External libraries and I can't use it in my code. What have I missed?

Comment: Did the build Sync complete without errors? Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: I didnt get any errors as far as I know. Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/mpWshceG
I also put the build.gradle there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong dependency, please change to this one and reimport/refresh:

```
implementation group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta7'
```

The incorrect one from the linked build file:

```
implementation 'org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:1.0.0-beta7'
```

Instead of `deeplearning4j` you should use `deeplearning4j-core`.

Comment: Hey that worked! I copied that line from dl4j's website, it seems odd to me that it was incorrect...